# Do I have a memory leak? (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, debugging, memory-leaks

I have an app written in nodejs that runs on a server. I have noticed (by manually checking the server load from time to time) that my app is starting with around 50MB total allocated RAM (from which aprox. 10 MB are HEAP) but after 6 days it is using a total of 100 MB (although the HEAP remains more or less constant).

First I've tried to debug it with Chrome but the debugger only monitors the HEAP portion of the allocated RAM (and I have not noticed any problems there). On the other hand I watched the debugger for a limited amount of time.

So, to further monitor the RAM usage, I've written the following code inside my app

```
var maxRecordedRam = 0;
ramCheck = setInterval(() => {
    let ram = process.memoryUsage();
    let ramRss = Math.round(ram.rss / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100;
    let ramHeap = Math.round(ram.heapUsed / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100;
    if ( maxRecordedRam < ramRss ) {
        // memory load is higher then the last recorded value
        maxRecordedRam = ramRss;
        modulUtile.log(
                "RAM: " + ramRss + " MB (Heap: " + ramHeap + " MB)", 
                "INFO"
        );
    }
}, 30000);
```

Please note that `modulUtile.log()` method is a kind of wrapper for `console.log`, that logs messages to a file.

After 6 days I have the following output in the log file (the file is larger, I've only picked some values):

```
[2019-08-23 07:10:19]    RAM: 44.27 MB (Heap: 10.03 MB)
.....
[2019-08-23 07:25:19]    RAM: 56.81 MB (Heap: 11.57 MB)
.....
[2019-08-23 09:13:19]    RAM: 65.85 MB (Heap: 15.72 MB)
.....
[2019-08-23 14:47:49]    RAM: 90.97 MB (Heap: 19.14 MB)
.....
[2019-08-25 09:49:52]    RAM: 93.9 MB (Heap: 10.66 MB)
.....
[2019-08-29 12:39:30]    RAM: 97.02 MB (Heap: 17.23 MB)
```

The HEAP allocation is up to 20MB during work hours and around 10 mb during the night and in the morning (when the app is kind of idle). But although the HEAP is going up and down, the total RAM is only climbing.

My question: Is it possible to have a memory leak outside the HEAP area (because as far as I know, only HEAP area is used for storing variables)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible for heap memory to "leak" into stack memory.

It might help to also print out the heapTotal and external values of memoryUsage().

If the heapTotal accounts for most of the spare memory, then the JVM is making more and more heap available to your program without relinquishing it back to the system.  This is not a memory leak in your code, and the memory may be returned to the system when the unused memory gets large enough to bother with.

If the external portion of the memory is growing, then some unmanaged .dll is consuming more and more memory, possibly due to a memory leak within it, or possibly because of thread mismanagement.  Debugging external libraries, especially those you have no control over, can be a pain.

If neither of those is growing, then your own code's stack is growing.  This could be caused by two things:  reiteration and thread mismanagement.

Are the number of threads used by your code increasing?  Then threads are hanging at some point, and new ones are spawning.  Each thread contains a small amount of stack that isn't returned until the thread properly exits its lifetime.

Reiteration should not be the culprit unless it's obviously possible, e.g., some functions can loop back into the main work flow through function calls instead of returning.

It's also possible, though unlikely, that the JVM is not properly tracking used heap.  The way you'd detect such a bug in the JVM is to run the program on a different JVM and see whether the numbers are roughly the same, or whether the new JVM starts reporting much larger heapUsed values.

Without further information, my suspicion would first fall on "the JVM is holding unused memory to avoid releasing and reacquiring it," followed by "an external .dll has a memory leak."

Answer (score 0):

So basically a heap memory is allocated as a part of RAM which is more of a hardware memory component, whereas a heap is a logical component allocated or created by a specific service or a set of services, in this case, your NodeJS service. 
Now in your case, it can very well be that pos the garbage collection the heap memory is being cleared but since your RAM has already allocated space for this memory in RAM and given the fact that usage is not much viz. 100mb out of 2Gb or so is less. So the system does not think that it should swap this out which the hard disk or any other memory storage available.

Also as stated in [this article](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/javascript-stack-size/), the JS V8 engine allocatees memory and separates it into A Stack and Heap memory allocation. The article will explain what different type of operations will cause either the stack or the heap memory to increase.

Given the above, I would encourage you to stress test your code to make it reach peak memory utilization where your heap and RAM usage is more than 80% of total RAM available to your device or VM, etc.

> There is an inherent trade-off between garbage collection throughput,
>   latency, and memory consumption. For example, garbage collection
>   latency (which causes user-visible jank) can be reduced by using more
>   memory to avoid frequent garbage collection invocations. For
>   low-memory mobile devices, i.e. devices with under 512 MB of RAM,
>   prioritizing latency and throughput over memory consumption may result
>   in out-of-memory crashes and suspended tabs on Android.

The above lines are from [this brilliant article,](https://v8.dev/blog/optimizing-v8-memory) which say that the memory allocation and deallocation can be controlled partially by prioritizing the GC or code execution latency. Which means you can prioritize when you want to destroy arrays or objects or set them null or how fast you want your requests to be processed and the concurrency allowed or in short amount of data which should be stored in memory and process concurrently thus reducing latency.

So all in all, although heap memory leaks may cause the rise in RAM usage, it won't be at the expense of each other as heap is part of RAM. So it may also be possible that RAM usage may be increased either because of stack memory or some other related service which may or may not be related to your NodeJS service. But all this will be evident once you can perform and benchmark multiple stress tests and analyze the results for yourself. As the behavior is very specific to your application code and how your code is structured.

About visualization, While you stress test your NodeJS application you can use [this tool](https://mlippautz.github.io/v8-heap-stats/) to analyze your code execution and the article mentioned above also gives a brief idea about what to watch out for.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. I've read the articles but I still don't know if it is possible to have a memory leak outside of the heap (the original question). All the debugging tools I've found are only for heap portion of the ram (including the one you suggested) and I don't have a problem there, as the heap is fluctuating with the server load.

Comment: I think that's what the article and answer(last couple of para) is trying to explain, a memory leak is conceptually not actually a leak from a virtual memory space to another memory space like a stack or in your case RAM. So your RAM usage suppose to say is 100Mb is including the heap memory of 20Mb and the other 80Mb is your NodeJS stack memory and other services running on your system. Thus the possible memory rise in RAM may be caused by other services. to check that you use `htop`. refer - https://askubuntu.com/a/138685 
---
OR  
---
In short - NO memory leaks don't work like that.

Comment: I know that a memory leak is not a transfer from one virtual space to another. A leak happens when the software keeps on creating elements without unreferencing them (and not allowing GC to free the memory). And there is my problem because, as far as I know, these elements are only created inside the HEAP area. About the `htop`, that is how I've first notice the problem (as I stated in the question). The memory can not be used by other services on the system, as `process.memoryUsage()` only reports the usage for the actual running process.

Comment: Doesn't that mean it is being used by the Stack memory .. as your heap is constant and in some way or the other your stack memory is raising...

Comment: That is right somehow. If the HEAP is not the problem then the stack zone can have problems. But, is that even possible? Because all of the examples I've found are only referencing the heap area. Even Chrome's memory debugging tool is only monitoring the heap portion. More or less, my question is something like: Is is possible to have a memory leak OUTSIDE the heap area? Or is it just that the operating system is not emptying the memory (somehow...) because there is no need for additional ram for other processes.

Comment: maybe you can try restarting the NodeJs process and benchmark each run with different load sizes, to see if this is happening again and that if similar behavior is observed in each run. This will at least give clarity to fact that there some side effect of the way NodeJS service is running which is causing the non-heap memory to rise.
Also, it can be the later as the numbers mentioned in ur case are very low for any RAM cleanup or GC to take place. testing it on higher stress will provide a more results ideally at par ~80 - 90 % available memory usage...

Comment: Also can u try and log out the `ram.external` usage

Comment: And the RSS - resident code segment is inclusive of stack and code and heap.. and it makes sense either the stack or code is casuing this .. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage